# Machine learning on dummy variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, many-categories

I have a dataset on which there are about 1000 dummy variables indicating location. I do not have access to lat/long.

I am using xgboost to train it. The more that I train it does seem to be lowering the test-set error. However, when I try to look at the branches of the trees using `trees = xgb.model.dt.tree(names,model = model2)` **all** values of the split (`trees$Split`) are a negative value (-1.00136e-05).

Considering that these are dummy variables (1 or 0) for a negative split value it will always go to the yes branch. My question is how is it even learning anything with a negative split value? It seems the more rounds that I let it train the better the algorithm gets in terms of test set error. This doesn't make much sense.

If it helps its a multi-class classification problem with 3 classes and the error metric is log-loss.

edit: to answer questions of standardisation and -1/1 see below:

> unique(as.vector(as.matrix(train_set)))

```
[1] 1 0
```

edit 2: This number seems to occur even on his basic example [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/demo/basic_walkthrough.R)

edit 3: Minimal example included:

```
require(xgboost)
set.seed(1)
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
train <- agaricus.train
bst <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(train$data), label = train$label, max.depth = 2, eta = 1, nround = 2,
               nthread = 2, objective = "binary:logistic")
trees = xgb.model.dt.tree(dimnames(train$data)[[2]],model = bst)
    print(head(trees$Split))
>>> [1] "-1.00136e-05" "-1.00136e-05" "-1.00136e-05" NA NA NA
```

## Solution

As Vadim points out below I was using a old version of xgboost (the one offered on cran). Use the following to update the version and you will get 0.5 as expected.

```
install.packages("drat", repos="https://cran.rstudio.com")
drat:::addRepo("dmlc")
install.packages("xgboost", repos="http://dmlc.ml/drat/", type = "source")
```

Comment: Are you sure they aren't coded as -1, 1?

Comment: perhaps you have a standardization somewhere

Comment: see edits above @rapaio

Comment: You really can't be sure that xgboost is not *internally* standardizing the variables without scouring the documentation and inspecting the source code, regardless of what your data looks like in R.  That said, I don't see any reason for a tree based model to standardize.

Comment: This certainly seems to be the case as it happens on the basic example when I inspect the tree.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because your data is in sparse format. E.g., enforcing the data to be dense in the basic example (using `as.matrix(train$data)`) would show the splits to be at 0.5.

For sparse "dummy" data, one is the only actual value that a feature might have. Thus, the search for best `split_value` for such a feature doesn't really move far from its initial value of zero, mostly just the [offset](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/ef4dcce7372dbc03b5066a614727f2a6dfcbd3bc/src/tree/updater_colmaker.cc#L473) with [rt_eps](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/ef4dcce7372dbc03b5066a614727f2a6dfcbd3bc/include/xgboost/base.h#L65).

Comment: I'm afraid I've already done as.matrix to change the data frame. The data isn't sparse

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: As requested minimal example included

Comment: This is the ["dense matrix"](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/eb169e4f73d6e51d4e7aac2a5e243db592039fc3/R-package/demo/basic_walkthrough.R#L22) from the "basic example". And I get the `[1] "0.5" "0.5" "0.5" NA    NA    NA` result from it using either the most recent or the pre-"brick" version of xgboost code on 64bit windows and linux. What xgboost code and what system are you running?

Comment: So it turns out that I had to update the xgboost via devtools and NOT the cran version.